# How to replace import syntax with require.ensure (for webpack)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I have some imports I am attempting to replace with the require.ensure from webpack. I am not entirely sure what I am doing incorrectly so here is my code:

Previously I had :

```
   import module1 from 'module1';
   import module2 from 'module2';
   import module3 from 'module3';
```

which I was then using in a switch case like so :

```
   switch (url) {
    case 'module1':
        return module1;
    case 'module2':
        return module2;
    case 'module3':
        return module3
}
```

This was working great. However i have removed the imports and am trying to replace them with require.ensure like so:

```
  case 'module1':
        return require.ensure(['module1'], (require) => require('module1'), 'module1');
    case 'module2':
        return require.ensure(['module2'], (require) => require('module2'), 'module2');
    case 'module3':
        return require.ensure(['module3'], (require) => require('module3'), 'module3');
}
```

This does not seem to work, I think I am mis-understanding how `require.ensure` works. How do I correctly use it in this case? Thanks!

Comment: You can't really. Your first use case loads the modules sychronously, while the second one loads them asynchronously. You'd have to provide an async API first.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks very much! Can you point me into the right direction for something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require.ensure` is *asynchronous*. It will load the module on demand if it isn't loaded yet. That's why you have to provide a callback. Once the module is loaded, the callback is executed.

Your original example is *synchronous*. All modules are loaded before any of the code is executed.

In order to load the modules on demand, you have to make the module API asynchronous as well.

Assuming the original module looks something like

```
import module1 from 'module1';

export default function loadModule(url) {
  switch (url) {
    case 'module1':
      return module1;
  }
}
```

a simple solution would be to make the function return a promise instead:

```
export default function loadModule(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    switch (url) {
      case 'module1':
        require(['module1'], resolve);
        break;
   }
}
```

(I am using the two argument form of `require` here instead of `require.ensure` because its easier to use in this situation).

Any callsite would have to be changed from

```
const module = loadModule('module1');
```

to

```
loadModule('module1').then(module => {
  // do stuff with module
});
```

If you make one function in the chain asynchronous, anything else that depends on it has to become asynchronous as well.

---

Note: If the value of `url` is already a module name and you just want to load that specific module, there is no need to have a switch statement at all. Just load the module directly:

```
function loadModule(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => require(url, resolve));
}
```

But you don't provide any context, so it's difficult to give a more specific solution.

Comment: Sorry for missing some context. I am trying to replace all the imports of my custom npm modules to async syntax, and hopefully have them be individual packages as well. The end goal is to only load them when they are needed (hopefully).

Comment: That makes sense. I'm doing the same thing in a project of mine. There, every parser has a `loadParser` method which uses the two-argument form of `require` to load the corresponding module automatically. For example: https://github.com/fkling/astexplorer/blob/master/src/parsers/js/esprima.js . Maybe looking around that codebase helps as well.

Comment: This is great, thank you. This is interesting... I am currently using the promise callback in that switch case you set up and it is creating a 1.bundle file, which is loading in the index fine, however it doesn't seem to play with the original bundle well. Maybe i should take a different approach.